# The process cannot access the file, because it is used by another process

Tags: c#, process, crash

I use a stream reader to read a file. Another program writes interval-white to this file using streamwriter.

Sometimes it happens, that the following error is displayed:

"The process cannot access the file, because it is used by another process".

I know why, but is there a way to check in C# if this file is being used by another process, so that it doesn't crash.
I'm connected to the streamreader / streamwriter.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not simply catch that exception?

Comment: Okay, maybe you have an example?

Comment: Found a dupicate.

Comment: Are those two processes your applications? Then you need to synchronize access: using IPC, named mutexes, file-locks, etc. Maybe you don't even need a file if process 1 prepare data for process 2?

Comment: This file is on a server and one program writes to this file and another program reads this file